# How to add facebook login to my own website?

Tags: facebook

Stackoverflow uses different ways to login to their website, e.g. with the facebook login.

With the facebook social plug-ins (see [social plugins](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/)) you can add a like button or a facebook login. But how it is managed by stackoverflow to connect the facebook account with a stackoverflow account ?

Comment: For example there’s the Registration plugin right there on the page you linked. And there’s ways to implement it by yourself, of course – just have the user connect to your app, get the information you need, and create a new account with your pages login system.

Answer (score 9):

Facebook Social Plugin: 
The Login Button
Facebook offers a host of what they call social plugins. The one we are interested in is the Login Button. Here are the basic steps involved in getting the button onto your webpage:

You need a Facebook app for your site. Go to https://developers.facebook.com/apps/ and click on the "Create New App" button.

Your "App Display Name" can be something meaningful. 
I usually go with the domain name for the site. You can use this same app for other purposes in the future as well. The "App Namespace" needs to be something that does not contain any special characters. 
I usually use my app display name without spaces, periods, etc.
Now you need to enter your "App Domain" and Website "Site URL." For the app domain enter the domain name on which your site is hosted. 
For the site URL enter the full URL of your website.
 For example, if your domain is name.com then your site URL should be something like http://www.name.com. 
Save your changes once you have the proper information entered.
Now you will have a page that shows yours "App ID" and "App Secret".
 Just leave that page open because you will need your app ID when you add the login button code to your page.
Now we need to go get the login button code from Facebook. Go to http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/ and click the "Get Code" button.
Copy the HTML5 code from the first box and for now put it just below the body tab of your webpage. The code should look something like this:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
   (function(d, s, id) {
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {
       return;
     }
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=APP_ID";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   } (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

In the code be sure to replace APP_ID with the app id you created for your Facebook app.
Now paste the code from the second box in whatever place you want the login button to reside. The code should look something like:

```
<div class="fb-login-button" data-show-faces="false" data-width="200" data-max-rows="1"></div>
```

I changed the data-show-faces attribute to false because with it set to true the logout button will not render when the user is logged in.

Answer (score 4):

The Facebook Login plugin only provides a way for you to log the user into your website. You must do the Link to your internal system yourself (as StackOverflow does). This means creating a new "User" based on the Facebook User's details.

For example, if you website uses email address as the "username", then you must ask facebook users to provide their email address or ask for the email address permission. Then, you create a new account for the user and give them a random password.

You must also change the login flow so existing users can sign-in with their email / password or their associated Facebook Account.

Answer (score 0):

follow this code after app registration and fb sdk download:

```html
<?php
require_once('lib/Facebook/FacebookSession.php');
require_once('lib/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php');
require_once('lib/Facebook/FacebookResponse.php');
require_once('lib/Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php');
require_once('lib/Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php');
require_once('lib/Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php');
require_once('lib/Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php');
require_once('lib/Facebook/GraphObject.php');
require_once('lib/Facebook/GraphUser.php');
require_once('lib/Facebook/GraphSessionInfo.php');
require_once('lib/Facebook/Entities/AccessToken.php');
require_once('lib/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurl.php');
require_once('lib/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookHttpable.php');
require_once('lib/Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpclient.php');


use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;

use Facebook\FacebookHttpable;
use Facebook\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\FacebookCurl;



session_start();
$app_id="";
$app_secret="";
$redirect_url="";
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($app_id,$app_secret);
$helper=new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper($redirect_url);
$sess=$helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
if(isset($sess)){
 $request=new FacebookRequest($sess,'GET','/me');
 $response=$request->execute();
 $graph=$response->getGraphObject(GraphUser::classname());
 $name=$graph->getName();
 echo 'hi $name';
 
}
else
{
 echo '<a href="'.$helper->getLoginUrl().'">Login with Facebook</a>';
}
```