# Adding a Facebook login in my website

Tags: java, php

Is it bad if I shared with the ones developing my website my Facebook client id and secret id so that they can create the Facebook logged in button?

He also asked me for all these other information and I gave it all to him to create the Facebook, Instagram, and Twitter logged in button on my website. I also gave him the ones for google.

INSTAGRAM

Client_name
Client ID
Client Secret 
Client Status
Website
Description

FACEBOOK

App_id
App_secret
App_page_id

TWITTER

Consumer_key
Consumer_secret

Comment: Repost of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11841725/how-to-add-facebook-login-to-my-own-website

Comment: @Akash not quite a duplicate, he is asking if it's secure to share that information with a 3rd party. Which is not, there's a reason the word "secret" is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### In short: No

This is a question the answer of which **depends heavily on the circumstances and kind of setup you have**, but in short these days its not a good idea as its easy to avoid the need to share these secrets.

The IDs are normally public so there is no harm in sharing that, but the secret keys should be entered directly into server's (or app service) environment settings if you can manage them yourself. Different hostings have different ways to enable this, consult your hosting provider and developer team to guide you.

### When its fine

If you are not technical yourself, don't want to go through the hassle of managing access to your server, find it hard to learn and trust your developers greatly then its fine and they would need it to do actual deployment.

**Remember**, while they are developing and testing the website/service they can use temporary app-id and secret keys that they themselves can get in most of the cases.

Follow up questions:

**Q.** If I go to the settings and ask for a new secret key for all of these social services, will it affect the programming of the developers and create a problem or will it be fine since the client id is good enough for the job?

**Answer** Yes if you reset the secret keys the service would fail and would require the new keys to be configured on the server. There are tons of guidelines on each of Facebook, Google, Instagram developer pages that you can read on this topic and are pretty easy.

**Q.** Can they get inside my Facebook, Instagram, etc if they have the secret Id?

**Answer** No the keys are for the app/service to allow your website request user's information who allow your app, not for accessing your account.

**Q.** Please tell me whats the worst thing that can happen with the secret  after sharing it with the developers if they do something wrong with it?

**Answer** Its basically a security risk. One of the worst things, IMO, that can happen is that they commit it into an open code repository or implement it in the wrong way so its accessible to anyone easily. That would allow attackers/hackers to get your app users to believe they are giving access to their requested data to your app (by using your app id and secret) in their attacks. But again this is heavily based on how careless the developers are, if they are good they would work to keep it secure. Ask them in your next meeting how they are using it and how it will be secure from other people copying it. Chances are they are good people and have taken this into consideration and would also explain it to you.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time to answer my question. Now if I go to the settings and ask for a new secret key for all of these social medias will it affect the progrming of the developpers and create a problem? Or will it be fine since the client id is good enough for the job...

Comment: Also can they get inside my facebook instagram etc if they have the secret id??

Comment: No the keys are for the app/service not for accessing your account.

Comment: Ok good but if I reste the secret id key will it give problems to the services?

Comment: Yes if you reset the secret keys the service would fail and would require the new keys to be configured on the server. There are tons of guidelines on each of Facebook, Google, Instagram developer pages that you can read on this topic and are pretty easy. 
Please remember to accept the answer if its satisfactory. I will update it shortly with information you have asked in comments.

Comment: ok now please tell me what s the worst thing that can happen with the secret client id after sharing it with the developpers if they do something wrong with it?

Comment: One of the worst thing that can happen is that they commit it into an open code repository or implement it in the wrong way so its accessible to anyone easily. 
That would allow attackers/hackers to get your app users to believe they are giving access to their requested data to your app (by using your app id and secret) in their attacks. But again this is heavily based on how careless the developers are, if they are good they would work to keep it secure. Ask them in your next meeting how they are using it and how it will be secure from other people copying it.